# boolean used as a flag in search a number in an array

Tags: c#

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int search = 10;
bool found = false;
foreach(var eachNum in numbers)
{
    if (eachNum.Equals(search))
    {
        found = true;
        Console.WriteLine("found");
        Console.WriteLine(search);
        break;
    } 
}
if (!found) // !found == false
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

In the example above, `if(!found)` means `if(found == false)`, the `found == false` makes  sense to me, but the `!found` does not. Why are these two the same, because `if !found == false`, than the value of found should be true.

Comment: Maybe would help to verbally say what you are seeing. `if(not true)`, `if(true is false)`, `if(false is false)`.. that sort of thing. I don't really know what you need help with though.

Comment: You're just confusing yourself by adding in `== false`. When checking a bool you do not need to ever compare it to a bool value. It is already a bool, so why compare it to a bool to get another bool? It just adds another complexity to understand.

Comment: Mentally replace `!` with the word "not" and things become much clearer.

Comment: sorry I write one thing wrong  My question is why if(! found) means (found==false)

Comment: @SuttonZhang `(!found)` does not mean `(found==false)`. It depends on what the value of `found` is.

Comment: yes, in this case, I set found = false; at the beginning, so if !found == false ,hence found should be true, but in this program, if(!found) and (found == false) gave the same output "not found". That is where I don't understand,why  if(!found)  (found == false) is the same here?

Comment: Gēnjù nín fābù de xìnxī hé nín xuǎnzé de dá'àn, wǒ jiànyì nín huā xiē shíjiān yuèdú [bāngzhù zhōngxīn wéndàng](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When found is false, !found is true. When found is true, then !found is false. !found doesn't mean found == false. Forgive my poor english. 国人的话，可以用中文交流一下。

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need someone to clarify what you are seeing.

Here are some cases you might see in your program:

```
//debug your program and watch the value of the variable named: found.
if (true)  //if "found" is true
{
    //enter
}
if (false)  //if "found" is false
{
    //don't enter
}
if (!true)  //if "found" is not true, which means it's false.
{
    //don't enter
}
if (!false)  //if "found" is not false, which means it's true
{
    //enter
}
```

As you've posted currently, the value of `found` will never be `true` though, because `search = 10`, and you do not have the value `10` in your `int[] numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of having different ways of writing the same boolean 
expression.

The `if` statement evaluates the expression it's given and executes the following code block if the expression evaluates to `true`.

`if (!found)` and `if (found == false)` are equivalent because the truth table for both expressions is the same.  The table below shows the possible values of the variable `found`, and the resulting values of each expression:

```
found    !found    found == false
---------------------------------
false    true      true
true     false     false
```

**As further explanantion:**

`!found` evaluates to the logical negation of the value of the variable, so if the value in `true` then it evaluates to `false`, and vice versa.

`found == false` compares the value in `found` with the value `false`, so if the value of `found` is currently `false`, then the comparison evaluates to `true` because the two values are the same.

**Another way to think about it** is that `!found` is another way to write `found != true`.